# Pass mobile iPhone image data from native IOS app to safari page WITHOUT image data leaving the phone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari

How can I pass large amounts of base64 image data (several phone camera or picture gallery pictures encoded in base64 png or jpg) from a native app to a local Safari web page opened externally by the native app (on the same phone as the native app) WITHOUT sending the image data off of the phone?

It is not acceptable to send the image to a server, open the page in safari and then have that page get the image from the server.

I can convert the images to base64 and concatenate them into a string. I can then pass them into a UIWebView and store them in a cookie or localstorage. But neither a safariViewController nor an external Safari page can access the cookie or local storage. And the data is too large to pass directly as a parameter in the URL invocation (safariViewController or external Safari). Encoding into base64 HTML in the native app also doesn't work because openURL() only works with http and https (not data:)

Comment: What do you mean by "a local Safari web page opened externally"?

Comment: @rmaddy I think they want to generate a local HTML "file" in their app and have Safari render it.  I don't think this will be possible due to the sandboxing of their app.